# How to use __repr__ method python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, repr

I need to define a class of polygons in 2D.
Each polygon defined by a list of tuples(coordinates) for example:

```
poly = [(0.5,0),(1,0.5),(0.5,1),(0,0.5)]
```

*(There is no need for sorting)*
The points are sorted clockwise starting from the most left point.

My task is to define this class properly
 `__init__`, `__repr__`  and  `is_inside(self, q)` function that checks weather a point is inside the polygon.

The `__repr__` method supose to print `'[(0.5,0),(1,0.5),(0.5,1),(0,0.5)]'`

So far this is what I have:

```
class Polygon2D:
    def __init__(self, pts):
        for index in range(len(pts)):
            self.index = pts[index]
    def __repr__(self):

        return str(self)
```

When I try to run it the program crashes. Please help me!!

Answer (score 4):

`str(self)` calls `self.__str__` which will delegate to `self.__repr__` which in your implementation calls `str(self)`, starting the whole circle again. So yes, you caused an infinite recursion.

Your more immediate problem is storing the `pts` list however. You are only ever storing the *last point*, discarding the rest. Assigning to `self.index` in a loop only results in the last assignment winning.

Just store `pts` directly, as an attribute, and simply turn *that* into a string as the result for `__repr__`:

```
class Polygon2D:
    def __init__(self, pts):
        self.points = pts

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.points)
```

Storing the whole list of points will also make implementing your `is_inside` function achievable.

Comment: first of all thank u for your answer:)

but dont i need to have an  easy acces to each point?
for example: poly.1 = (0,0.5)
remember that they are sorted in a specific way

Comment: If you pass `[(0.5,0),(1,0.5),(0.5,1),(0,0.5)]` to the `__init__()` method you will have easy access to the points. All you need to do is `poly.points[<whatever_index>]` the same way you would for a normal list not assigned to a class instance. Assuming you first do something like `poly = Polygon2D(your_points_list)`

Comment: @ofersimchovitch: Just access `self.points[0]`, etc. to index all your points. The list retains the order. don't try to create new attributes for each index.